# How to correctly remove .git/refs/changes/*

Tags: git, gerrit

My team uses gerrit for handling revision. For each revision, gerrit creates a branch-like thing in the git repository, that looks like `.git/refs/changes/1/2/3`.

Now we had to rewrite our repository's history (git filter-branch), and theses changes refer to commits in an 'alternate timeline', and should be removed.

Just deleting files beneath `.git/refs/*` seems to be discouraged by the git manual.

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can remove the `.git/refs/changes` and you will also have to rewrite the db of Gerrit. Look below for more details:

http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/repo-discuss@googlegroups.com/2010-05/msg00014.html

Comment: The above link URL redirects me to some bad-looking garbage site.  Maybe this is a better link http://osdir.com/ml/repo-discuss/2010-05/msg00014.html

Comment: Now also the second link has gone bad.